# Deep linking not working on any other browser other then Chrome for Android Apps

Tags: android, mobile, deep-linking, branch.io

I have integrated [**branch.io** SDK](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/) for deep linking.

The flow of my deep linking is when I clicked on URL it will open my app if it's already installed in users phone else it will redirect to [play store](https://play.google.com/store) from their user can install the app.

This flow working perfectly if I browse link using chrome browser but if I use any other browser apps for browsing like **UC**, **Opera** or **Samsung** default browsers this flow is not working, either way, it's redirecting to play store.

Anyone have a solution for this please let me know!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tanmay, I believe you also sent in an email. Some default browsers are problematic -- if you send over your user agent string we can take a look (whatsmyuseragent.com). Regarding Opera, can you send us a link to the version you're using that doesn't work? Then we can test it and issue a patch if necessary

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise it is very hard to help you...

Comment: I'm using branch.io and is working fine for me, what you mean "browser link"? you click on the link inside this browser or you make your link open this browser?

Comment: @toobsco42 , branch.io integrated solution has been updated. Please check.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

On `older Android devices` there are known issues getting apps to open using `URI Schemes and App Links`. These issues are not limited to Branch links.

Comment: Where are these issues documented?  Are there any fixes for this? I came across another dev that mentioned the same thing https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/223#issuecomment-299310394

Comment: I am using Braze and under the hood they use sendgrid to send out emails.  It looks like `digital asset links` files need to be set up.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Branch does support both Braze and SendGrid. Here are links to the docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/emails/braze/ and https://docs.branch.io/pages/emails/sendgrid/. With regards to issues with the browsers on older Android devices, there is quite a bit of variance and not a lot of support. If you really need information on this you will need to approach the phone manufacturer.

Comment: Where do you get the SHA256 fingerprint of signing cert ?  This needs to be added to the digital asset links file.

Comment: Here is a link to the App Links docs on Branch's site: https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linking/android-app-links. They do explain how to generate the SHA256 fingerprint. If you have difficulty, reach out to their support organization, which is very good: support@branch.io

Comment: @toobsco42 , branch.io integrated solution has been updated. Please check.